# Add / Remove column in admin/content/node

Tags: nodes, forms

How can I add / remove columns in admin/content/node ?

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can modify this page by implementing hook_form_alter in your custom module.

But the best approach is using [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) and [VBO](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module create your own contant admin page with columns and filters that you need. Module [Administration Views](http://drupal.org/project/admin_views) will help replace Drupal core admin page with your own.